# Выполнить одну функцию при клике на разные кнопки

Tags: jquery

Есть, например, спойлер. Он открывается, когда мы кликаем по классу `toggler`, т.е: `$('.toggler').click(function())`. А как открывать его по двум классам одновременно, например: `toggler` и `__header`?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('.toggler').click(function() {
    
    var spoiler = $(this).parent().parent();
    var status = $(this).attr('hide-content');
    
    if(status === 'true') {
      
      $(this).addClass('icon-minus').removeClass('icon-plus');
      $(this).attr('hide-content', 'false');
      
      let content = spoiler.find('.__content');
      content.removeClass('__hidden');
      
    } else {
      
      $(this).addClass('icon-plus').removeClass('icon-minus');
      $(this).attr('hide-content', 'true');
      
      let content = spoiler.find('.__content');
      content.addClass('__hidden');
      
    }   
    
  });
  
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata');

body {
  background: #000C0B;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.spoiler {
  margin: 30px auto;
  background: #001514;
  max-width: 500px;
  font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
}

.spoiler .__header {
  padding: 20px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.065);
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  position: relative;
}

.spoiler .__header i {
  position: absolute;
  right: 12.775px;
  top: 12.775px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.165);
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.265);
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.spoiler .__content {
  padding: 20px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: justify;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.065);
  border-top: none;
}

.__hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//at.alicdn.com/t/font_o5hd5vvqpoqiwwmi.css">

<div class="spoiler">
  <div class="__header">
    test
    <i class="toggler feather icon-plus" hide-content="true"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="__content __hidden">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec neque nunc, eleifend at ligula ut, scelerisque rutrum quam. Vivamus gravida a neque vitae vehicula. Vestibulum in bibendum lorem. Integer sit amet porttitor sapien. Morbi gravida dictum purus, id vulputate ligula aliquet eget. Sed eget congue magna. Pellentesque congue, dui in rutrum ornare, justo mauris gravida felis, ut fringilla quam justo sed tortor. Fusce ornare dolor nec tincidunt lobortis. Pellentesque condimentum gravida felis, at porttitor urna. Aliquam feugiat vulputate dapibus.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="spoiler">
  <div class="__header">
    test
    <i class="toggler feather icon-minus" hide-content="false"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="__content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec neque nunc, eleifend at ligula ut, scelerisque rutrum quam. Vivamus gravida a neque vitae vehicula. Vestibulum in bibendum lorem. Integer sit amet porttitor sapien. Morbi gravida dictum purus, id vulputate ligula aliquet eget. Sed eget congue magna. Pellentesque congue, dui in rutrum ornare, justo mauris gravida felis, ut fringilla quam justo sed tortor. Fusce ornare dolor nec tincidunt lobortis. Pellentesque condimentum gravida felis, at porttitor urna. Aliquam feugiat vulputate dapibus.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Тк в вашем примере __header родитель toggler то при клике на toggler будет также срабатывать клик на __header. Те можно просто переместить функцию на __header. Конечно надо ее переписать тк элемент вызвавший событие будет другим.

Comment: А в общем случае если бы действительно нужно было бы повесить одну функцию на разные элементы можно просто описать функцию отдельно. function myclick(e) {...}; и выполнять ее в каждом элементе $('.toggler').click(function() {myclick(this);}; $('__header').click(function() {myclick(this);}; Конечно тут надо как то еще учитывать что this будут разные.